# Symfony "Invalid env" - only "word" characters are allowed

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently trying to get a Symfony project up and running. The problem is when I try to setup the database I keep getting

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException] 
Invalid env(resolve:DATABASE_URL) name: only "word" characters are allowed.
```

I edited the `.env` file to have my local database credentials. The `DATABASE_URL` variable looks like the following:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://user:pass@192.168.10.10:3306/db_name?charset=utf8mb4&serverVersion=5.7"
```

Where of course, user, pass and db_name are the credentials.

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found something in [doctrine recipe](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/1.6/config/packages/doctrine.yaml). It's likely because you are using symfony 3.3 with symfony/flex so you would need to remove the `resolve` keyword, ie. in your `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
```

See this [news](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-advanced-environment-variables) for more information

Comment: I removed the `resolve:` keyword just like the comments said. But now I'm getting: Environment variable not found: "DATABASE_URL". Which is strange because I do have it defined in the .env file.

Comment: Make sure you are running your app in `dev` environment. Dotenv component is not loaded by default in `prod`. See your `bin/console` and `public/index.php` file and how the dotenv component is used in them.

Comment: Running it on a Homestead VM. How can I manage the environment?

Comment: I don't know but in CLI you can use `--env=dev`

Comment: just in case someone stumble upon the same problem, you can set `APP_ENV` to `dev` at VM level (`Homestead.yaml`).
see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead#environment-variables

Comment: I once got this error because of a typo in my services.yaml: '%env(ROUTER_HOST))%' - note the extra ")".